# What is this component marking 100K?

Tags: identification, components

What is this component, a capacitor, resistor or conductor?

I have a portable pH meter but cannot measure alkali/basa. I think the sensor working perfectly: out 0-5V equals 0-14pH.

I try to measure with omh scale, the result over 1M sometimes over 4M, when I measure with the  capacitor scale the result is 2nF.
I try to change with resistor of 100K, with a capacitor of 10uF but pH meter cannot measure.

[image: marking 100K]

Thanks

Comment: looks like a polystyrene capacitor. Value *could be* 10pf. or *could be* 100pf

Answer (score 5):

It's a 10pF 10% polystyrene capacitor. 100 means 10 * 10^0 pF = 10 pF, K means 10% tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think they could make plastic caps as low as 10pF.

So my guess is 100 pF K=10%

... and it must be an RF (AM Radio) suppression cap on the ADC input of ICL7126

Comment: Why can't you make a plastic cap that low? Surely there's no limit to how low you can make?

Comment: I'll send you 100 LEDs if you find one

Comment: https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-BC-Components/BFC242090012?qs=%2Fha2pyFadugr1miht1MS24LjhQZUELTIBQyxc8FYQFE%3D

Comment: Polypropylene film. That's plastic. I'll pm you my address for the LEDs?

Comment: https://uk.farnell.com/lcr-components/fsc-160v-10pf-1pf/cap-10pf-160v-10-ps-through-hole/dp/9519955

Comment: Damn. Tony gonna run out of LEDs :p

Comment: Nah I got about 10k surplus sitting in the garage. What colour of 5mm > 16Cd  of LEDs would you like 4500'K White Red, Yellow